# What to put on top of existing vinyl

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

First of all, I am REALLY not the manual type of guy. I am renting this place, with this flooring in the entrance and the kitchen, that is in very bad shape. It's old, very used, which males it very dirty very quickly. The owner already told me I could do what I want, that it doesn't matter since when I leave he will redo the condo to sell it...

I have 300 square feet to cover.

I was considering peel and stick tiles at first, but I hear from a lot of people that it will unpeel, and that it is not good, etc.

The cheapest tiles at Home Depot are $0.59 per square foot. They told me to apply some glue under however. Total would be under $200.

Then the owner told me to find vinyl planks. I found some, the brand is Beaulieu, it is $1.69 per square foot on sale, can be laid over the existing linoleum, no glue. Total: around $500

Then I thought about Vinyl sheets. I found some at Lowe's or Home Depot that are decently priced. I could cover everything for like $300. Without cost of glue (if needed, I don't even know). The issue here is that the existing vinyl has some a texture though it's not very deep, but I am scared it would show up through the new one.

Would it, even if I get a vinyl sheet that is 3 millimeters thick?

Any advice or other option?

Comment: How long do you want to be there? A year? 10 years?

Comment: If you're "really not the manual type of guy" you should probably have Home depot come and lay some mid-grade vinyl over the top and be done. I'd bet it would be right around that $300 mark with labor. You'll have a nicer finished product than you'll get yourself.

Comment: At least a year and a half

Comment: Given your timeframe: peel and stick. It won't curl, and if it did, nobody would care. Telegraphing of the old pattern? Pfft!

Comment: LOL at this typo: "which males it very dirty very quickly".

Answer (score 1):

Self-adhesive tiles bond well if the surface is prepared well. If you can strip it chemically and apply a bonding primer you shouldn't have problems.

To install vinyl sheet over vinyl you should usually level the existing embossing using, get this, an *embossing leveler*. You simply trowel it onto/into the texture of the old floor to make it flat. This technique does depend on both the old and new flooring products being appropriate for that use.

What I'd do depends on how long I expect to be there. Chances are I'd find some nice rugs that I could take with me when I go.

Comment: I have thought about the rugs, however I don't like having a rug in the kitchen.